# Object Identification Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Currently I am researching about viable approaches to identify a certain object with the image processing techniques. However I ams struggling finding them. For example, I have a CNN capable of detecting certain objects, like a person, then I can track the person as well. However, my issue is that I want the identify the detected and tracked person like saving its credentials and giving an id. I do not want something like who is he/she. Just giving an id in that manner.

Any help/resource will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a database, Store the credentials you needed for later use e.g object type and some usable specifications, by giving them some unique ID. CNN already recognized the object so just need to store it in database and later on you can perform more processing on the generated data. Simple solution is that to the problem you are explaining.

Okay I got your problem that you want to identify what kind of object is being tracked because cnn is only tracking not identifying. For that purpose you have to train your CNN on some specific features and give them some identity like objectA has [x,y,z] features. Then CNN will help you in finding the identity of the object.

You can use openCv to do this as well, store some features of some specific objects, then use some distance matching technique to match the live feature with stored features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something called [ReID](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02984). There are a lot of papers about it in CVPR2018.

You can imagine that you would need some sort of stored characteristic vector for each person. For each detected person, gives a new ID if it does not match any previous record, or returns the ID if it does match a record. The key is how to compute this characteristic vector. CNN features (intermediate layer) can be one. Gaussian mixtures of color of the detected human patch can be another.

It is still a very active research field and I think it would be quite hard to make a accurate one if you don't have much resources/time at hand.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that how to extract the identifying features from the image portion. SURF, SIFT and OBR are some basic approaches but they are both overwhelming and time consuming algorithms but can extract some storable data about the detected object from the CNN. Thanks for the reply

Comment: That really depends on *your application*. For person re-identification, the facing angle (towards or away from camera) can already mess up all those feature extraction/matching algorithm that you have mentioned.